# Atlas for the ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, 3d, ellipsoids

> Find an explicit atlas for the ellipsoid $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

---

I've been trying to modify the stereographic projection for the sphere to an atlas for the ellipsoid but can't get it to work.

Comment: Just go with the six orthogonal projections, then.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Can you elaborate a little? Can you give an example of one?

Comment: Like the inverse map of $(x,y)\mapsto \left(x,y,c\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\right)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah got it, thanks.