# Atlas of ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, ellipsoids

My question relates to the following problem and its solution, as described in the comments section of the post.

[Atlas for the ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689714/atlas-for-the-ellipsoid)

Specifically, in finding an atlas for the given ellipsoid, the solution proposed comprises the charts given by the  'inverse map' of $(x,y) \to \left(x,y,c\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2}\right)$. Is the image of the inverse of this map really an open set? It doesn't look like one.

Comment: A chart isn't a chart until you specify the domain. What domain/codomain are you using here? For these charts, a typical choice is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}<1$.

Comment: That would make sense, but why isn't the boundary included?

Comment: So that the domain and codomain are open, mainly. Also, it would fail to be smooth at the boundary, since the derivative diverges.